# How can I add css to a specific div on 4th level in hierachry?

Tags: html, css

How can I add css to a specific div on 4th level in the hierachry below?

```
`<div id="sp-top2">
    <div class="sp-column">
        <div class="sp-module jmoddiv jmodinside">
            <div class="sp-module-content">
                Welcome admin
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>`
```

I want to add magrin-left to the 
    `<div class="sp-module-content">`
but without adding any other attributes on the above code. 
How can I do it?

Comment: use `.sp-module-content` as a selector

Comment: The thing is that I can't because the .sp-module-content is used by other elements and I don't want them to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Include,

```
#sp-top2 .sp-module-content{
   margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: This one does it! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Always Welcome.. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
#sp-top2 .sp-column .sp-module .sp-module-content {
 color: blue;
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

add:

```
#sp-top2 .sp-module-content {margin-left:XXpx;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use class selector for css
for exmple-

```
.sp-module-content{
    margin-left:100px;
```

}